# Twitter code issue using scribe in android

Tags: android, scribe

I am implementing twitter in my application using scribe.I am able to login and getting the code back which is showing to user. Here the problem is that, i have to force the user to manually type the code and when he submit that code i will get the access token. But i don't want to show this code to the user. Instead i can use this code and use the verifier to get the accessToken back. Is it possible ?

Comment: Was my answer adequate?

Answer (score 1):

```
/*
    The below example assumes you already have the following variables:

    oAuth -> Scribe OAuthService Instance
    requestToken -> Request token received from your callback
    verifier -> Verifier received from your callback
*/

// GET ACCESS TOKEN

    Token accessToken = null;
    accessToken = oAuth.getAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);

// TEST ACCESS TOKEN BY GETTING A PROTECTED RESOURCE

    if (accessToken != null)
    {
        // CREATE, SIGN, AND SEND REQUEST

            OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, "https://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json");
            oAuth.signRequest(accessToken, request);
            JSONObject response = new JSONObject (request.send().getBody());

        // EXTRACT NEEDED REQUEST RESPONSE VARIABLES (IN THIS CASE JUST THE SCREEN NAME AND TWITTER ID)
        // (NOTE: make sure to do some error checking to make sure accountName and networkAccountId are not empty)

            try
            {
                String accountName   = "@" + response.get("screen_name").toString();
                int networkAccountId = response.get("id").toString();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                // LOG ERROR MESSAGE

                    Log.e("Your_Tag","Get Access Token Error: " + e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```